# Pip install can't find existing version

Tags: pip, scipy

python version : `3.9.1`
pip version: `21.3.1`

My requirements.txt contains this line:

```
scipy==1.3.3
```

After running `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Got this:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> scipy==1.3.3 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0,
> 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, **1.3.3**, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0rc2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0rc2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0rc1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.3.3

Which is totally nonsense, because as you can see the given version is within the list of versions provided by pip in the error message

Comment: Hardware? OS? M1 + MacOS X?

Comment: @phd  windows10 windows10

Comment: Is that the complete error message you are getting?